# Speed of field and data in wire

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, speed-of-light, data

The speed of field in wire is near the speed of light (speed of field not electron) so why speed of data is in MBPS, I mean why a byte dose not transport with light speed (field speed).

Comment: Because bits per second is a measure of modulation of the signal, not of speed of the signal.

Comment: For the same reason the speed of a car is measured in meters per second, but the rate of cars passing by a certain point on the freeway is measured in cars per second rather than meters per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two measurements have nothing to do with each other. The MB/s is how long it takes to transmit a message of a given size. It has nothing to do with the delay between transmission and reception, which is essentially what the speed of light would give.